# Upload JPEG via JSON

Tags: java, android, api

Tenho um código que pega uma foto da galeria ou faz com que tire uma foto e gostaria de ajuda pra enviar essa imagem via JSON pra minha API, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

Meu código:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(userChoosenTask.equals("Tirar Foto"))
                    cameraIntent();
                else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Escolha uma foto da galeria"))
                    galleryIntent();
            } else {
                //code for deny
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Tirar Foto", "Escolha uma foto da galeria",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_addinf.this);
    builder.setTitle("Adicione uma foto ");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(Activity_addinf.this);

            if (items[item].equals("Tirar Foto")) {
                userChoosenTask ="Tirar Foto";
                if(result)
                    cameraIntent();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Escolha uma foto da galeria")) {
                userChoosenTask ="Escolha uma foto da galeria";
                if(result)
                    galleryIntent();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}


private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
}

private void cameraIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);


    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    livview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    livview.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Comment: O que você não sabe exactamente? Enviar ou receber?

Comment: Gostaria de enviar